# Change PHP version after installing through make

Tags: php, linux, debian

I recently installed php 8.2.7 onto my Debian 10 server, compiling it from source and installing it through 'make install'.  I would now like to change this version but am unable to, installing a new version does not change it, nor does using update-alternatives.  The command works and I am able to select a different version, yet the results of 'php -version' do not change.  Help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to compile PHP 8.2.7 via source code?

Comment: I was having issues installing 8.2 through apt.  I've since resolved those issues and now am stuck on the broken version I compiled from source

Comment: is your  ```sudo update-alternatives --config php``` showing list of php version that you installed ?

Answer (score 0):

**For Command Line** (which you're asking)

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2 
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.2 
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.2 
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize8.2 
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.2
```

**For Apache**

For example you have PHP 7.4 installed, you should first disable Apache module for other PHP versions.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
```

Then, enable PHP 8.2.7 module in Apache server:

```
sudo a2enmod php8.2
```

Also, the best practice, if possible, is to remove other PHP versions and re-install the desirable version ONLY.

Comment: Unfortunately this has not worked, using update-alternatives has no effect

Comment: what is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --display php` and `which php`?